# Class instantiated elsewhere and this is used to access it

Tags: java

I am trying to play around with class instantiation and `this`.

In the below example, the `testresult` class will be instantiated and stored. 
`this`  will be used to pass that class instance as a parameter to another class.

Is this proper usage of  `this`  as the class is instantiated elsewhere?
Not sure why I see error as "The constructor `testfail(new Handler(){})` is undefined".

Code snippet:

```
public class testmain {
    private testresult tr;
    private testfunc tf;

    public testmain() {
        tr = new testresult();
        tf = new testfunc(tr);
    }
}

public class testfunc {
    private testresult storeit;

    public testfunc(testresult inst) {
        storeit = inst;
    }

    // this will be running as seperate thread  running forever.
}

public class testresult {
    private testfail tp;

    public void function() {
        tp = new testfail(this);  //----> error new Handler(){} undefined

    }
}

public class testfail {
    public testfail(testresult tr) {
        ///
    }
}
```

Edit : The error due to inner class

```
       public class testresult {
             private testfail tp;
                private class test {
                    public void function() {
                    tp = new testfail(this);  ----> error   
                    //  new Handler(){} undefined

                            }
                        }
                }
```

Comment: The error specifically is that you don't have a constructor that has the Handler object as a parameter.  This is happening because your reference to `this` is probably referring to the function called `function()`. 
 As a side note, circular references between classes like you have isn't a great design and should be redesigned.

Comment: yes I had written function() inside another private class in the code, hence "this " was referring to the inner private class than the one i had intended.

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code will compile.  Because `testfail` accepts an argument of `testresult`, using `this` will work, even though it's awkward and not something one *normally* sees.

Unless you overrode your `testfail` constructor by introducing another constructor that accepted a `Handler` as an argument, this compilation failure is expected.

As an example:

```
public class testfail {
    public testfail(testresult tr) {
        ///
    }

    public testfail(Handler hr) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The class has only one constructor, so I am not sure how it can be overridden by the undefined constructor. Will there be any hidden constructor in java ?   Also  I am attempting to come up with design to avoid singleton. so may be these invocation look bit awkward.